# Multi-threading with SQL - what table hints to use for Select?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading

I have a C# app that is multi-threaded. The application's purpose is to find an available proxy server stored in a SQL server table to connect to.

The table contains **200 proxies**. The **maximum concurrent proxy connections** allowed is 5.

The table has the following columns:

(ProxyId int, IpAddress varchar, IsSocks bit, ConnectStatus tinyint, LastConnected datetime)

ProxyId is a identity column, ConnectStatus has 3 values

- 0: available (updated by C# app)
- 1: being connected to (updated inside the sp below)
- 2: connected (updated by C# app)

I have the following stored procedure defined which will be called from the C# app:

```
Create Proc GetNextAvailableProxy

AS

Declare @proxyId int, @ipAddress varchar(20), @isSocks bit

if (Select Count(*) From Proxies Where ConnectStatus > 0) < 5 Begin

    Select Top 1 @proxyId = Id, @ipAddress= IpAddress, @isSocks = IsSocks 
    From Proxies with (updlock, readpast) 
    Where ConnectStatus = 0
    Order By IsNull(LastConnected, '1970-01-01')

    Update Proxies Set ConnectStatus = 1
    Where Id = @proxyId

    Select @proxyId ProxyId, @ipAddress IpAddress, @isSocks IsSocks;

    return;
End

Select Null ProxyId, Null IpAddress, Null IsSocks

GO
```

The above sp gets the next available proxy, and if there are 5 proxies being connected to or connected, the C# app receives Null for proxyId and wait for 2 seconds before attempting again.

The C# app will set the ConnectStatus = 2 when the proxy connection is established successfully, and ConnectStatus = 0 once the work is done.

My question: is my sp written correctly with the right choice of table hint? I don't know **what table hint I should place on the Select Count(*) statement.**

Comment: I think you can replace the select + update with just the update, it can also fetch values into variables, that way you shouldn't need updlock -- with select you'd probably need holdlock too. If you add waitfor delays into the procedure it's easier to test what happens in each step.

Comment: I'm not sure, because Update From doesn't support Order By... I tried but it didnt work.